# C# P/Invoke missing type

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying running this p/invoke method for long file path in c# using VS2015. However, EFileAccess EFileShare ECreationDisposition EFileAttributes are not present in the namespaces. If I change them to FileAccess, FileShare, FileMode and FileAttributes the errors went away. Are those types interchangeable in the context? What I was missing in my project?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
    string lpFileName, EFileAccess dwDesiredAccess, EFileShare dwShareMode,
    IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, ECreationDisposition dwCreationDisposition,
    EFileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

public static void TestCreateAndWrite(string fileName) {
    string formattedName = @"\\?\" + fileName;
    // Create a file with generic write access
    SafeFileHandle fileHandle = CreateFile(formattedName,
        EFileAccess.GenericWrite, EFileShare.None, IntPtr.Zero,
        ECreationDisposition.CreateAlways, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

    // Check for errors
    int lastWin32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    if (fileHandle.IsInvalid) {
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(lastWin32Error);
    }

    // Pass the file handle to FileStream. FileStream will close the
    // handle
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileHandle,
        FileAccess.Write)) {
        fs.WriteByte(80);
        fs.WriteByte(81);
        fs.WriteByte(83);
        fs.WriteByte(84);
    }
}
```

Comment: `are not present in the namespaces` well, you need to define them. I remember that I once checked for equivalence. Some were equivalent, some were not.

Comment: But they were supposed to be imported from kernell32.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't import an enum. A native DLL has no way to define it. At the ABI boundary an enum is just an integer. An enum is purely a .NET concept.

Define the enum yourself. (In practice this means stealing it from somewhere.)